# CodeMirror:How to change the specified token style?

Tags: codemirror

I've just began to use codemirror. Now I'm facing some problems that I don't know how to solve them. It's about change the class with some specified token [For example, I want to change this "let" style：](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj31J.png).

I've tried to use `getValue()` or `getLineHandle()`, but it seems like not to work. I should maybe get the specified dom object, but I don't know how.

Comment: You want to change the class of `cm-keyword?`